# Having trouble reading the Zero cross signal using Pigpio

Tags: gpio

I am trying to control an AC Light dimmer using the pigpio python library. [Light dimmer](https://www.banggood.com/RobotDyn-AC-Light-Dimmer-Module-For-PWM-Controller-1-Channel-3_3V5V-Logic-AC-50hz-60hz-220V-110V-p-1244351.html?akmClientCountry=America&gmcCountry=US&currency=USD&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_elc&utm_content=frank&utm_campaign=pla-mix-us-pc-0626&gclid=Cj0KCQiAkMDiBRDNARIsACKP1FG1lUQlGBgvdaVTMoAEwdeOtrDFy5XSvarR2d-1v4tWCrcOHaeGIxwaAi3AEALw_wcB&cur_warehouse=CN)

I can see the input AC source and the zero cross signal wave on my oscilloscope.  As I understand it I need to use that signal to time the pwm output in order to dim the AC signal.  When I attempt to read that pin all I get for output is 1.
Here are the signals, the yellow is the AC source and the blue is the zero cross output:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import pigpio
pi = pigpio.pi()
while True:
   value = pi.read(17)
   print('value is: ' + str(value))
   sleep(.05)
```

It connects to GPIO17 and the output is always 1.  I am using a Rasberry pi zero W.

**Edit****

From the replies I used the RPi.GPIO library instead and the result was the same.

```
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING)

def saw_it_rising(channel):
    print("rising " + str(channel))

GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, saw_it_rising)
while True:
    result = GPIO.input(channel)
    print("res " + str(result))
    sleep(.05)
```

This printed 1 every time and never triggered the "rising" callback function.  I tried moving it to the GND and it printed 0 so it seems to be working okay.

Comment: I would suggest to first check your program without the dimmer.  Just connect GPIO17 to ground and see if still get a flat High line. Dimmer spec: https://penzu.com/p/b50c80e2

Comment: Yes, you are right in saying that the dimmer (python) program uses the ZeroCrossing signal (GPIO17) to interrupt the Rpi, then the callback function uses a PWM GPIO pin (say GPIO18) to PWM control the firing time of the triac. (Also see the schematic of my dimmer learning notes): https://penzu.com/p/b50c80e2

Comment: I wouldn't use the pigpio Python module like that for this application.  pigpio Python uses a client/server model so each pi.read() will take of the order of a millisecond and each reaction would probably take a millisecond as well.  I suggest trying the RPi.GPIO Python module.

Comment: I can't understand your scope photo. It seems to be set to 1V/div. Then the yellow line is 4V peak-to-peak signal with 60 Hz frequency. This can't be mains. Even 110VAC is around 300V peak-to-peak.

Comment: The yellow comes out of a transformer that knocks it down to 13VAC.